# I am very new to python but for some reason the forex_python currency conversion package is returning an error and I can't work out why

Tags: python, forex

my code is

```
from forex_python.converter import CurrencyRates

forex = CurrencyRates.get_rates('USD', 'EUR')
print(forex)
```

the error I get is the following:

```
 File "/Users/asjbentley/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/forex_python/untitled0.py", line 12, in <module>
    forex = CurrencyRates.get_rates('USD', 'EUR')

  File "/Users/asjbentley/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/forex_python/converter.py", line 55, in get_rates
    date_str = self._get_date_string(date_obj)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_get_date_string'
```

I have done the pip install of the package. The function the error is referring to is in their package. This is a simple script which I should have no issues running.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source code, [`get_rates`](https://github.com/MicroPyramid/forex-python/blob/master/forex_python/converter.py#L54) is a function that accepts a `base_cur` as first argument and a `date_obj` as second argument. So if you pass a `str` to the second argument, it'll try to use a `datetime.datetime` object and it'll throw the error.

Maybe you meant [`get_rate`](https://github.com/MicroPyramid/forex-python/blob/master/forex_python/converter.py#L64), with `base_cur` as first argument and `dest_cur` as second argument (both `str`s)?

Answer (score -1):

from datetime import date
from forex_python.converter import CurrencyRates

#Utilisez la date actuelle
current_date = date.today()

#Appel de la méthode get_rates avec un objet de date
forex = CurrencyRates()

rates = forex.get_rates('USD', 'EUR', date_obj=current_date)